# Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I'm trying to install a driver (wifi isn't working) for my `Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)` as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) by installing the `firmware-b43-installer` package. However, I receive the following error: `E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer`.

I already tried the [bcmwl-kernel-source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl) package. It doesn't solve my problem.

Why can't I find the package `firmware-b43-installer` although it's still in the docs? Are there other ways to find a driver for my network controller?

**EDIT**

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) I have multiverse enabled. I have the following line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted multiverse
```

Comment: Yes. See my edit for the exact way I have (tried to) enable it.

Comment: True. Changing xenial-backports to xenial solved it. If you wish to post an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.