# Can't install mysql on Ubuntu 18.04, 404 not found

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error when I try to install mysql on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7 

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:   libnvidia-common-390 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The following NEW packages will be installed:   mysql-client-core-5.7 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded. Need to get 6,985 kB of archives. After this operation, 31.5 MB of additional disk space will be used. Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64
5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64
5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried

```
sudo apt update
```

followed by

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

My sources.list file looks like this

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

I just tried autoremove followed by update and upgrade and this is what I got when I ran again with --fix-missing

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.7 --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 mysql-client-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,985 kB/6,992 kB of archives.
After this operation, 31.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 212399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

Comment: Hi, did you try with `--fix-missing?` as it suggested? And also running `apt get autoremove` as well?

Comment: @BenjaminR see my edits to the post above in response to your question.

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/89100/400278) as it may help you out with your issue

Comment: @dank144 Have you tried pinging `91.189.88.161`? I want to rule out a network problem.

Comment: @BenjaminR pinging that address works fine, I went here and doesn't look like that particular version listed in the 404 not found error is still there 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/

Comment: @dank144 Can you mark Karellism's answer as correct since it worked for you? :)

Comment: Apologies, I tried to upvote instead of marking it correct and I couldn't because I'm too green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `sudo apt install mysql-client`

If I am correct this will also install a few dependencies.
With the `mysql-client-core-5.7`being one of them.

I hope this helps you with your problem.

Comment: I dunno, I successfully installed just `mysql-client-core-5.7` on my 18.04 LTS machine, so I wonder if there is something else going on for the OP.

Comment: If this doesn't work, maybe using the MySQL repository will help?
See [MySQL apt doc](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) for information.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, solution was for me to remove repositories sources related to mariadb, after that i did purge mysql and all related packages, reload sources, reboot and reinstall mysql again and it worked !!!!