# Unable to install anything in Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal

Tags: software-installation, gnome-terminal

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 10 but I am getting these message whenever trying to install anything.

```
    ~$ sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
[sudo] password for john: 
error: cannot install "canonical-livepatch": Post
       https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup
       api.snapcraft.io: no such host
~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

Comment: What's the output of `nmcli networking connectivity check`? api.snapcraft.io should resolve to a set of IPs, try [other DNSs](https://www.opennic.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you’re repositories are outdated or corrupt.

Try
    sudo su root
    apt update

```
apt full-upgrade -y
```

If that fails (it should if your repositories are messed up.)

Try this

```
apt-get check && apt-get update
apt-upgrade
```

Note you may need to run the update a couple of times.