# VirtualBox on 20.10

Tags: virtualbox

Does `apt` on 20.10 have a virtualbox package?

I see that `apt install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms` has worked on previous releases but on 20.10

```
 apt install virtualbox 
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Package virtualbox is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source

 E: Package 'virtualbox' has no installation candidate
```

`apt search` doesn't find anything like it.

Comment: Yes.. it's found in `multiverse'`so your package tools won't find it unless you have `multiverse` enabled - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  (if you use `rmadison` you can go beyond your enabled repositories or actual release, but that tool isn't instaled by default)

Comment: @guiverc Yes. My `sources.list` had no `multiverse` entries so I added them in using the `universe` lines as template. Then with `apt update` and `apt install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms` the application installed. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://packages.ubuntu.com can easily and authoritatively answer any is-package-X-in-the-Ubuntu-repositories question.

[image]

Note that Virtualbox is in the multiverse repository. Since your apt cannot locate the package, you likely do not have the repository enabled. [Here's how to enable it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

Comment: Ah. The multiverse lines were missing from my sources.list. So I copied the `universe` lines and changed `universe` to `multiverse`. VBox then installed. Interesting that I've been installing VBox for years without having to do this. So something happened to my sources.list during `do-release-upgrade.`