# How to install fonts in Libre Office on Chromebook?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, chromebook

I've **ASUS C532** Chromebook. I've installed LibreOffice on that from the GNOME store. I've options to get Times new roman fonts on other applications like google docs but due to some conditions I've to move from Google docs to LibreOffice but now the problem is there is no Times new roman font in LibreOffice I got some videos on YouTube to do so saw some commands to install `ttf-mscorefonts` but that didn't work.

```
tampeg610@penguin:~$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependecy tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ttf-mscorefonts
tambeg610@penguin:~$
```

Comment: You will need to enable the multiverse repository, run `sudo apt update`, and then install `ttf-mscorefonts`. [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) This answer works for Ubuntu. In case you are not using Ubuntu, please ask a question at unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please indicate your version of Ubuntu and LO.